# Modifying output names using for in Matlab

Tags: matlab, string-concatenation

I'm trying to change output names using `for` in Matlab. I'm reading daily files, so I'd like the outputs to also have the day printed on their name. This is a simplification of what I've got so far:

```
day=['1','2','3','4','5']; 
for i=1:length(day) 
  namefile=['datafromday',num2str(day(i)),'.nc'];
  [var1,var2,var3]=read(namefile);
  var1_*=var1;
  var2_*=var2;
  var3_*=var3;
end
```

The * marks where I want to have the day number on. I've tried the same combination as in `namefile` but was unsuccessful.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: It's better not to use separate variables. A cell array would be much easier to deal with in the rest of the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a 2D *cell array* instead of separate variables. First index of the cell array will correspond to `day`, second will correspond to `namefile`. (Also, don't use `var` as a variable name, as there is a function with that name).

```
day = ['1','2','3','4','5']; 
vars = cell(numel(day),3); %// change "3" as needed
for i = 1:length(day) 
  namefile = ['datafromday',num2str(day(i)),'.nc'];
  [vars{i,:}] = read(namefile);
  %// Now the file names are in vars{i,1}, vars{i,2} etc
end
```

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I have a lot of days and many different variables. I'm not using `var` for variable names. I'm quite new to Matlab so I don't know much about cell arrays and other stuff, so I'd like just a way of adding the day number on the output name. Imagine I have this instead:
    `var1 = temperature`
    `var2 = depth`
    `var3 = salinity`

I'd like to have different outputs for different days, i.e `temperadure_day1` or `depth_day2`. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible. Check [`eval`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). But that is considered bad practice.